# Managing tables with same primary keys (Access 2010)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm fairly new to Access and am trying to convert what was a previously poorly managed database to a slightly better working version.

The biggest issue is that the database contains several 'main' tables that all have the same primary key. I know that's not ideal but in this case, I'm not sure its avoidable as it needs to be this way for privacy concerns + there's a lot of different fields so I'm not sure if we'd approach the cap.

Basically, the database is to house records for surgeries for later research purposes. There are two major primary keys. Several tables (for instance, OperativeData + Complications) use a 'Surgery ID' as a primary key. Other tables (for instance, PatientDemographic + MedicalHistory) use a 'Patient ID' as a primary key. There are 9 such "main" tables in the database.

I have two 'major' issues I'm trying to solve:

1) Making sure things will always match up across tables. If we were to create a query wanting to integrate patients' medical history and their complications.. I obviously need everything to line up. I also need to be able to update from queries/forms as we don't want everyone to have access to the underlying tables.

2) I want to create an easy way to add a record to ALL tables at once. Ideally, this would be a form where I can put in a patient #, surgery # and some other basic information. It would create an entry on EVERY table even if none of the other info would be populated yet. (One person inputs new patients into the database regularly but it may be years before the other info is put in as it may not be currently part of a research project).

How exactly can I go about solving these two issues?

My current attempt at a solution has a "Master Table" setup. This table has a primary key of "Surgery #" and a foreign key of "Patient #" (because surgery # will always be unique but a given patient may have multiple surgeries). Using this table as a link, I made a relationship between all of the other tables. (Each table with the same primary key linked to eachother as one-to-one and then every table also linked to this master table).

This helps things line up when I'm doing queries but I'm running into a lot of issues when trying to update from a query (recordset is not updateable, probably because it's one-to-many relationships?).. but doesn't solve the data entry problem. I read about using a subform but it sounds like I would need a subform for each of my main tables?

Hopefully I've laid out the issues clearly but please let me know if you have any questions. I obviously can't upload the database itself but I can try to get a similarly constructed database with sample data if it helps.

Thank you in advance for any help or tips you can provide!

Comment: There is no need to have a record in each table. There should only be records that contain actual usable data. It sounds like you are trying to do everything in a single form. That is not a good approach and will only lead to more problems down the road. If you need to see everything on one screen, then you should use a main form with subforms. You didn't ask, but since you are fairly new to Access, if there are privacy concerns, your back end should not be in Access. It should be in a more secure server database, like SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. As for security/privacy, the database is actually set a private server already. It's unfortunately not up to me as to combining all of the main databases, however. I don't want to do everything in a single form because there would just be way too many entries to make on it.. there will be some data that won't need to be entered at time of record creation. I am only planning to use a form to create the initial record and then want to use queries to populate various fields of my choice at that time (+ to analyze the data since I will be pulling fields from various tables)

Comment: But I'm not sure what you mean by I don't need to have records in each table? For instance, if I want to add a new surgery to the database, I want to make sure it is added to each table so that the data will eventually line up if that table's fields are queried. If I don't add surgery X to a table, I'm worried that someone else will come along later and add surgery X + 1 first under surgery X's autonumber in other tables is... and the data would be useless.

Comment: You need to read up on relational database structure, primary keys and foreign keys. PatientDemographic should be your master table with PatientID (autonumber) as primary key. MedicalHistory would have PatientID as a foreign key (NOT autonumber) and MedicalHistoryID (autonumber) as a primary key. OperativeData would have PatientID as a foreign key (NOT autonumber) and SurgeryID (autonumber) as primary key. Complications would have SurgeryID as a foreign key (NOT autonumber) and ComplicationsID (autonumber) as primary key. Of course, there are other ways, but this is common.

Comment: That was my next experiment, the current database is set up as I described which is obviously faulty. I've decided to instead properly normalize the database from scratch, present the advantages of doing it this way and hope it will be incorporated. My design includes two tables: "db Surgery" and "db Patient" that houses ALL of the info previously held by the nine master tables (i.e. complications fields in surgery and medical history fields in patient). These will be linked 1-to-many with referential integrity enforced.

Comment: I will then create queries for each of the previous nine master tables so the data can still be browsed in that fashion and updated that way if needed. No-one will ever touch the tables (and I may create a back-end database) unless just to add new fields entirely. Any updating will be done via queries/forms. I shouldn't have any issue with updating this way.. and adding new records should be easy using a form/subform design! My only concern now is being able to copy the data over without unknowingly misaligning the data but should be okay. Thanks for the prodding to do it properly!!

Comment: db Surgery would have PK 'Surgery ID' (autonumber) and FK 'Patient ID'. db Patient would have PK 'Patient ID'. Also haven't thought about the cascade update/delete options but sounds like I shouldn't enable these based on my research (this way, worst case scenario all of the data gets wiped for a given record but the surgery ID and patient ID remains.. so things can be patched up).

Comment: Sounds like you are getting there, but you still need to learn more than you can get from this one thread. However, two additional comments. Get rid of the spaces in field names and definitely split your application into FE/BE.

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to learn on the fly since this is obviously not my day job (nor will I ever be doing this again in the future.. this is just a research project for the summer). I know spaces are bad in field names if you are doing your own coding specifically, but I don't anticipate doing that.. and the spaces make things more legible.. will look into it though. Definitely planning on doing FE/BE if I can work out the particulars with the private server. Definitely appreciate any tips on how/what you think I should learn and please submit an answer so I can give you credit for helping